# How to get the page source from specific link in Java?

Tags: java, xml

Is it possible to get the `inputStream` of particular website content or it's page source into String?

For instance, I want to download the whole html tag from particular website into string or xml. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes of course you just have to do something like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    URL url;

    try {
        // get URL content
        url = new URL("http://www.mkyong.com");
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

        // open the stream and put it into BufferedReader
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                           new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

        String inputLine;

        //save to this filename
        String fileName = "/users/mkyong/test.html";
        File file = new File(fileName);

        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }

        //use FileWriter to write file
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

        while ((inputLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            bw.write(inputLine);
        }

        bw.close();
        br.close();

        System.out.println("Done");

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

CREDIT :  mkyong

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at guava's `CharStreams` class.

```
CharStreams.toString(new InputStreamReader(..))
```

will save you from writing much boilerplate code.

[Here is doc](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/io/CharStreams.html)